# Evaluate integral of $F.ndA$ by the divergence theorem.

Tags: calculus

$F=\langle \sin y, \cos x, \cos z \rangle$   and $S$ is the surface of $x^2 +y^2 \leq 4$ and $|z|\leq 2$

Here is what I got.

$div F= -\sin z$

since this is a cylinder $-2 \leq x \leq 2$ and so is $y$ so

$\int_{-2} ^2 dz \int_{-2}^2 dy\int_{-2}^2 -\sin z dx=16 \cos(2) -16\cos(-2)$

but the answer in the back of the book is zero. Did I set the range for $x$ and $y$ wrong?

Comment: Diane: As is very common on this site, I edited for *formatting only*.  Why did you roll the edit back?  Was the content changed in any way?

Comment: I might click on that button accidentally. Sorry, I'm doing integral for 5 hours long, so sometime I don't know what I'm doing.

Comment: The integration limits are wrong, corresponding to a cube.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks *almost* good to me - though, you've got an issue with your $xy$ bounds, which describe an integral over a box, not a cylinder.

The simplest way to express your integral is
$$
\iiint\limits_{C} -\sin(z) \, dV,
$$
where $C$ is the solid cylinder in your problem.  Since $C$ is symmetric over the $xy$-plane, we can apply the odd symmetry of the sine function ($\sin(z)=-\sin(-z)$) straight away to see that the answer is zero.

Alternatively, if you really want to compute antiderivatives, you could set the integral up in cylindrical coordinates:
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^2 \int_{-2}^{2} -\sin(z) \, dz \, r \, dr \, d\theta.
$$
In this case, we'd still come to $\cos(2)-\cos(-2)$.  This is again zero, as the cosine function is even.

Comment: ah, I alway have problem with trig identities. Can you tell me what is my issue with the bounds please?

Comment: so you got that by letting $x=r Cos(\theta)$ and $y=r sin (\theta)$?

Comment: @DianeVanderwaif Yes - using cylindrical coordinates.  Though, as I indicated in my last edit, even that might not be necessary.